# Can i edit on-hold or closed questions with different subject to reopen?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

I have questions which are closed or held. And i read 'How do I ask a good question?' tutorial for keep the rules. And i wanted to edit this questions to remove closed tags. I wonder that can i edit this questions with different subject. If I do that then pre written answers will become meaningless. Is it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's still basically the same or closely related question, by all means edit it to improve it.

If it has been closed, and you edit it, it goes in a review queue and will be reopened if it's become on-topic or reached the necessary standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a new question, simply ask it by clicking the "Ask Question" button at the top right of any page on the site.

Editing a question should only be used to refine the question or to add details.